# Using nlp.pipe() in Spacy to get doc objects for Dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nlp, spacy

I am using Spacy nlp.pipe() for getting doc objects for text data in pandas Dataframe column but the parsed text returned as "text" in the code has **length** of only **32**. However, **the shape of dataframe** is **(14640, 16)**.
Here is the data [link](https://www.kaggle.com/crowdflower/twitter-airline-sentiment) if someone wants to read the data.

```
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
for text in nlp.pipe(iter(df['text']), batch_size = 1000, n_threads=-1):
  print(text)

len(text)
```

Result:

```
32
```

Can someone help me with this what is going on? What I am doing wrong?

Comment: What do you expect to return from `len(text)`? It's used to return the length of the `text` which is probably a `str`. Try to print just `text` to know what I mean

Comment: @Anwarvic I know what `len(text)` do but not sure what it is doing here in my code. According to my code loop is iterating the dataframe `df` through rows containing text and the shape of `df` is **(14640, 16)**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Spacy Documentation of `Doc` object [here](https://spacy.io/api/doc), the `__len__` operator gets "the number of tokens in the document.".

The last text in your data is:

```
>>> df['text'].values[-1]
@AmericanAir we have 8 ppl so we need 2 know how many seats are on the next flight. Plz put us on standby for 4 people on the next flight?
```

After running the `nlp.pipe()` method, this sentence will be tokenized into 32 tokens which what you're asking for. To verfiy that, try runn the following code after `len(text)` and will get the exact result:

```
>>> last_tokens = [token for token in text]
>>> last_tokens
[@AmericanAir, we, have, 8, ppl, so, we, need, 2, know, how, many, seats, are, on, the, next, flight, ., Plz, put, us, on, standby, for, 4, people, on, the, next, flight, ?]

>>> len(last_tokens)
32
```

### EDIT

You can iterate over the tokens of each `doc` returned from the pipeline like so:

```
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
for text in nlp.pipe(iter(df['text']), batch_size = 1000, n_threads=-1):
    for token in text:
        print(token)
    print('\n')
```

Comment: But I think I am iterating over all the rows not the last one `for text in nlp.pipe(iter(df['text']), batch_size = 1000, n_threads=-1):` How this code gives only `len` of last text?

Comment: Yeah of course... but after you finish the loop the remaining `text` is the last item in the dataframe. Try it out yourself to make sure!

Comment: So how to get all the text of rows as doc objects for getting tokens from text? From the above code I am not getting tokens in required form of Spacy.